# JQuery toggle removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website at the moment, and have used a template to create a Menu bar. The menu includes + and - icons which toggle when a submenu is open and closed.

The menu itself works flawlessly, but these icons which look to be from a JQuery library or something similar aren't rendering correctly.

Could someone explain how to remove them at all?

The JQuery code is below, but to see it fully rendered view the JSFiddle link.

[See the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn1kykbh/) to understand better what I'm saying. You may need to enlarge your browser window to see the full sized menu.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.menumaker = function (options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this),
        settings = $.extend({
                format: "dropdown",
                sticky: false
            }, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).find(".button").on('click', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
                    mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
                } else {
                    mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
                    if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                        mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                    }
                }
            });
            cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
            multiTg = function () {
                cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
                cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                    if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
                    }
                });
            };
            if (settings.format === 'multitoggle')
                multiTg();
            else
                cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
            if (settings.sticky === true)
                cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
            resizeFix = function () {
                var mediasize = 700;
                if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                }
                if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                }
            };
            resizeFix();
            return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
            format: "multitoggle"
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a CSS issue, not a js library:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{
  position:absolute;
  top:17px;
  right:11px;
  width:8px;
  height:2px;
  display:block;
  background:#ddd;
  content:''
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:14px;
  right:14px;
  display:block;
  width:2px;
  height:8px;
  background:#ddd;content:'';
  -webkit-transition:all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition:all .25s ease;
  transition:all .25s ease
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/wn1kykbh/5/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of these properties, you need to play with `height` values and positions (`left, bottom, right, top`) to place them correctly :

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{
  position:absolute;
  top:17px;
  right:11px;
  width:8px;
  height:2px;
  display:block;
  background:#ddd;
  content:''
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:13px;
  right:14px;
  display:block;
  width:2px;
  height:10px;
  background:#ddd;content:'';
  -webkit-transition:all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition:all .25s ease;
  transition:all .25s ease
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn1kykbh/6/)

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers already state, this is a CSS issue, not a jQuery one.

The `:before` pseudo element inside your anchor tag has an 80px height when not on hover state. You can sort this out by adjusting its height and position.

But since you want to remove it, you can remove away the `:before` and `:after` style definitions on your CSS, or set their `content` property to `none`. This will prevent them from rendering at all.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    content: none;
}
```